# Retrieving tx.origin and msg.sender from blockchain data

Tags: web3js, logs, receipts

In Solidity, origin and sender can be easily differentiated through [*tx.origin* and *msg.sender*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/whats-the-difference-between-msg-sender-and-tx-origin/1894#1894), respectively.

Is it also possible to obtain both sender and origin of a specific transaction from the data in blockchain itself? The *from* field obtained with *getTransaction* and *getTransactionReceipt* seems to always be *tx.origin*.

Specifically, I would like to do so with the JS API. I suspect that somehow processing the information in the transaction logs in the transaction's receipt is probably one way to go, but haven't figured out how yet (although I would expect some simpler way, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: There is no easy way or API to get the `msg.sender` for (internal) message calls.**

In the [Ethereum protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) there's only transactions and message calls.  A transaction is a type of message call, and both `tx.origin` and `msg.sender` will always be the value of the `from` field.

A transaction may perform other message calls, but these are not transactions (even though a popular blockchain explorer labels them inaccurately as "internal transactions").  These (internal) message calls are not published on the blockchain, so there is no easy way or API to get their `msg.sender`.  To find out how contracts call each other, the transaction needs to be processed through the EVM (for example, https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm).

---

If you are the author of the contracts, every time a contract gets invoked, it could use an event to emit the value of `msg.sender`, and then you would be able to use [`getTransactionReceipt` and parse the logs.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1381/42)