# Are there any libraries/tools for encoding input for data field of web3.eth.call method?

Tags: web3js, abi, calldata

You can call contract functions using web3.eth.call method. Information on which function to call and what arguments to pass to this function is encoded according to the rules that can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI). They are relatively easy to understand, and I believe somebody out there has already developed some libraries/tools for this purpose.

I'd be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction! Thank you!!!

Comment: using web3.js here is an example
[link](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js)

Comment: Since you're using web3.js, using [Contract Methods](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) is much simpler than using a direct `web3.eth.call`.