# eth_sendTransaction for function with address type parameters

Tags: transactions, python, abi, calldata, encoding

I'm interacting with my local private blockchain created using geth. I'm able to use eth_call, but now I have some problems with eth_sendTransaction.

The signature of the function is this:

```
function addContract(bytes32,address)
```

So in python I do:

```
addContract = sha3hex8('addContract(bytes32,address)')
```

sha3hex8 is a function I've created that I'm sure works correctly because I use it for all the eth_call I've done.
Then I need to add the two parameters.

How can I attach the two parameters with the right encoding? Should I simply concatenate at the end the address parameter without the starting 0x?

Comment: I suggest to use a library like Web3.py to perform these tasks and not try to do them yourself if you are not sure what you are doing: https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py/

Comment: +10 to @Mikko's suggestion.  Otherwise you need to ABI encode the parameters, http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7675/are-there-any-libraries-tools-for-encoding-input-for-data-field-of-web3-eth-call which leads to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/encoding-decoding-contract-abi-data.  [`getData`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) may also help as suggested in
http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I've already know the Web3.py library, but I still have to encode correctly the parameters. When I have to call a function with 1 bytes32 parameter I'm able to do it, while with 2 parameters I've problems, and I'm trying to figure out why