# Location of coder.js in Windows

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3-providers

I have web3.js working on my Windows machine, I need to access web3 library called `coder.js`, according to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js) answer the location of that library is `web3/lib/solidity/coder.js`

But I cannot find these libraries, does anyone know what is the location on web3 libraries on Windows 7?

Comment: You are checking in the web3 node module only right. I have downloaded web3 module and checked it is present there. Try reinstalling the node module.

Comment: Yes checking in node module only I have found one file there named "coder.js" but it was actually a HTML file that means the file is "coder.js.html", but cant find the js file

Comment: What I see is a js file. The link to the js file of node module in github is https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/solidity/coder.js  Try removing the node module and reinstalling it.

Comment: yes I too got that file on git hub but cant find it on my machine, I will try reinstalling it hopefully it works

Comment: If you have installed web3 using npm, then you have a folder `node_modules`, inside that folder there's the web3 folder.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question 
there are multiple instances of the file 
at locations

1.

```
C:\Users\user1\node_modules\web3\lib\solidity
```

2.

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ethpm-registry\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\solidity
```

3.

```
`C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\truffle-migrate\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\solidity`
```

4.

```
C:\Users\User(LPT-APR2015-02)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\solidity
```

And there are some more, But I think the correct one to use is first in the list.

we can use this coder.js to parse the transaction log. 
Ref:- [How do I parse the transaction receipt log with web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js)