# Does a token-transfer always have a value of zero?

Tags: tokens, message

Usually a token-transfer has a (ETH) value of zero and the amount is encoded in the input-data payload. Some projects even distinguish between normal and other transfers by checking for zero:

https://github.com/trezor/trezor-mcu/blob/master/firmware/ethereum.c#L341

The question is: is it enforced somewhere? Otherwise e.g. in the TREZOR example someone could hide a token-transfer by sending some ETH with it ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment above saying "Yes, token-transfer always has a value of 0" is wrong.

The correct answer to the question is that--no--there is nothing that precludes a token transfer and an ether transfer from happening in the same transaction.

It ***is*** true to say that most ERC20 token smart contracts are coded to disallow it, but that is in no way the same thing as saying it's not allowed.

Distinguish between the smart contract code and the Ethereum protocol. In the protocol you can do anything you want relative to sending both 'data' and 'value' in the same transaction. A smart contract must be coded to disallow this. The fact that most token contracts do so, doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, usually the token contract will reject a transfer with a non zero value.

For a contract method to receive ethers it should be marked as `payable`, but the transfer method does not have such modifier. Moreover most token contracts will reject any transfer made after the crowdsale is over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, token-transfer always has a value of 0 (as the value attribute is associated with Ether), but the data part will have some value when doing a **token transfer**. I have worked on this topic recently, I myself wanted to know the same. To understand it much better I had to filter some transactions and check myself how does an ETH transaction differ from token transfer. All the below transactions are taken from **TESTNET**:

### ETH TRANSFER

Transaction Hash: [0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6)

**Transaction log:**

```
> web3.eth.getTransaction("0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6");
{ blockHash: '0x06111bf75fb9108dc5596ddbb6e2e843ee13830987688a90df2ab0772815fa96',
  blockNumber: 1488295,
  from: '0x76e0bb92b6f8d431af2fe1bafd304eb832241619',
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: { [String: '31000000000'] s: 1, e: 10, c: [ 31000000000 ] },
  hash: '0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 261,
  to: '0xb1aa0ac057639e534a89b095853befc4d6d264cf',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: { [String: '1000000000000000000'] s: 1, e: 18, c: [ 10000 ] },
  v: '0x2a',
  r: '0x3b4202fda27b6fdfb6985e10ffcd7b5f9f2a64e31fc75d444d6a7684a75f3b',
  s: '0x5bb67429e6cae209f53ad5c1538d0c3d0035f12e92a569c0b2898512d9cdeae5' }
```

**Transaction Receipt**:

```
> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6");
{ blockHash: '0x06111bf75fb9108dc5596ddbb6e2e843ee13830987688a90df2ab0772815fa96',
  blockNumber: 1488295,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  from: '0x76e0bb92b6f8d431af2fe1bafd304eb832241619',
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: '0x6a29376fb5c83a4617fecc1b95c1353f37711912128fd3b6bce9dde57b8130b3',
  to: '0xb1aa0ac057639e534a89b095853befc4d6d264cf',
  transactionHash: '0x27c3fe1bc90723e5d7e0dbc3429e71faa967a623c8e4c49df0739283c17718e6',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

If you carefully check the above logs, the value property in the **Transaction Log** has the value of 1000000000000000000 wei i.e. 1 Ether. and the Input is **0x**

Similarly the Logs in the **Transaction Receipt** is an empty object. Which will not be empty when a token transfer happens.

### TOKEN TRANSFER

Ropesten Transaction Details: [0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677)

**Transaction Log**

```
    web3.eth.getTransaction("0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677");
{ blockHash: '0x34ee516310a59407712455ec87bd76046a1e68f5c631dc8e6b4bb903b8c92834',
          blockNumber: 1535104,
          from: '0x76e0bb92b6f8d431af2fe1bafd304eb832241619',
          gas: 223616,
          gasPrice: { [String: '22000000000'] s: 1, e: 10, c: [ 22000000000 ] },
          hash: '0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677',
          input: '0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000002b3425ce986f9f0f599758f4fb33158ca671e83e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
          nonce: 267,
          to: '0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9',
          transactionIndex: 7,
          value: { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
          v: '0x1b',
          r: '0x4ad36e9eefd233abce864b3e53b86d1b937bcea83223564e4f56cc7defbcde3e',
          s: '0x22f256f9fe62187dc0e8942981ef52ae3643d04f50e00957c94e10b8da4e3116' }
```

If you check the above transaction Log, it clearly suggests that this transaction was a Token Transfer, as the below properties help us:

`- Input: '0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000002b3425ce986f9f0f599758f4fb33158ca671e83e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'`

**0xa9059cbb** is the hex for transfer.
**0000000000000000000000002b3425ce986f9f0f599758f4fb33158ca671e83e** is the address to which the token was sent with left padding upto 64 places
**0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001** is the number of tokens to be sent left padded upto 64 places.

`value` property is 0x0 (this shows no ether were sent)

**Transaction Receipt**

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677");
{ blockHash: '0x34ee516310a59407712455ec87bd76046a1e68f5c631dc8e6b4bb903b8c92834',
  blockNumber: 1535104,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 352435,
  from: '0x76e0bb92b6f8d431af2fe1bafd304eb832241619',
  gasUsed: 36979,
  logs:
   [ { address: '0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9',
       topics: [Object],
       data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
       blockNumber: 1535104,
       transactionHash: '0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677',
       transactionIndex: 7,
       blockHash: '0x34ee516310a59407712455ec87bd76046a1e68f5c631dc8e6b4bb903b8c92834',
       logIndex: 6,
       removed: false } ],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008080000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000001000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: '0x9840ddaa4571522013623410420a11689fc44184d52d541d4f1067adcdde9e8c',
  to: '0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9',
  transactionHash: '0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677',
  transactionIndex: 7 }
```

As I said earlier, the logs property when a ETH trasnfer happens is empty but when a token transfer happens logs property has an object which helps in identifying to/from which address the token got transferred. the data property helps in knowing the amount of tokens transferred.

```
address:'0x5c99dadde01ce61ab5b5536d566bf41ecd17e3a9',
    topics:
     [ '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
       '0x00000000000000000000000076e0bb92b6f8d431af2fe1bafd304eb832241619',
       '0x0000000000000000000000002b3425ce986f9f0f599758f4fb33158ca671e83e' ],
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
    blockNumber: 1535104,
    transactionHash: '0x14632d129a6aac7365483a3000470ece443a19a73f242cba1f1944f78889a677',
    transactionIndex: 7,
    blockHash: '0x34ee516310a59407712455ec87bd76046a1e68f5c631dc8e6b4bb903b8c92834',
    logIndex: 6,
    removed: false } ]
```

If I remember it correctly,to distinguish much more clearly between transactions, you can try using the a logParser made using SolidityEvent Library which can be found inside web3.js. Here is the [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js) to the same.