# How to decode event log info from contract?

Tags: contract-development, events, logs, web3.py

I have structure of event in my Solidity code like `event test(address investor, uint256 priceinWei)`.

I make a request to etherscan to get all logs from contract on specific addres and get

```
{  
   'address':'...',
   'topics':[  
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
      '0x0000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
      '0x000000000000000000000000409fefe0212a75d8c117ac834123d462bce9635c'
   ],
   'data':'0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012f94bfef30bf32b8d',
   'blockNumber':'...',
   'timeStamp':'....',
   'gasPrice':'0x4a817c800',
   'gasUsed':'0x182b7',
   'logIndex':'0x8',
   'transactionHash':'...',
   'transactionIndex':'0xc'
}
```

**Question**: How can I get address and price from it. Should I decode "data"? Instead `...` I of course got values, just don't want to show it.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to do it in a hard way, here is an example of Uniswap v2 PairCreated event:

```py
def decode_pair_created(log: LogResult) -> dict:
    """Process a pair created event.

    This function does manually optimised high speed decoding of the event.

    The event signature is:

    .. code-block::

        event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);
    """

    # The raw log result looks like
    # {'address': '0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f', 'blockHash': '0x359d1dc4f14f9a07cba3ae8416958978ce98f78ad7b8d505925dad9722081f04', 'blockNumber': '0x98b723', 'data': '0x000000000000000000000000b4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 'logIndex': '0x22', 'removed': False, 'topics': ['0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9', '0x000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48', '0x000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2'], 'transactionHash': '0xd07cbde817318492092cc7a27b3064a69bd893c01cb593d6029683ffd290ab3a', 'transactionIndex': '0x26', 'event': <class 'web3._utils.datatypes.PairCreated'>, 'timestamp': 1588710145}

    # Do additional lookup for the token data
    web3 = log["event"].web3
    token_cache: TokenCache = log["context"]

    block_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(log["timestamp"])

    # Any indexed Solidity event parameter will be in topics data.
    # The first topics (0) is always the event signature.
    token0_address = convert_uint256_string_to_address(log["topics"][1])
    token1_address = convert_uint256_string_to_address(log["topics"][2])

    factory_address = log["address"]

    # Chop data blob to byte32 entries
    data_entries = decode_data(log["data"])

    # Any non-indexed Solidity event parameter will be in the data section.
    pair_contract_address = convert_uint256_bytes_to_address(data_entries[0])
    pair_count = int.from_bytes(data_entries[1], "big")

    # Now enhanche data with token information
    token0 = token_cache.get_token_info(web3, token0_address)
    token1 = token_cache.get_token_info(web3, token1_address)

    data = {
        "block_number": int(log["blockNumber"], 16),
        "timestamp": block_time.isoformat(),
        "tx_hash": log["transactionHash"],
        "log_index": int(log["logIndex"], 16),
        "factory_contract_address": factory_address,
        "pair_contract_address": pair_contract_address,
        "pair_count_index": pair_count,
        "token0_symbol": token0.symbol,
        "token0_address": token0_address,
        "token1_symbol": token1.symbol,
        "token1_address": token1_address,
    }
    return data
```

[Full example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps.py) available on [web3-ethereum-defi project](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi).

Comment: Excalty what i was looking for. Great exampple

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reference `testEvent` to the event using

```
    var testEvent = Contract.test({}, {fromBlock: startBlockNo, toBlock: 'latest'});
```

and then use `watch` or `get` to on this reference to retrieve the events:

```
testEvent.watch(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        // do what you want to do with the event data
    }
});
```

or

```
testEvent.get(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        // do what you want to do with the event data
    }
});
```

Within the `if(!error) {...}`part you can access the data of the event from your question using `result.args.invester`and `result.args.priceinWei`.

The difference between `watch` and `get` is that `get`will only give you past events, while `watch` will get you past events and watching for new ones.

Comment: can't find it in web3 python. more accurately: yes, I can set listener but, don't get decoded info

Comment: It is javascript :/