# Decoding transaction logs of Pancakeswap's router by web3.py

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, pancakeswap, logs, bscscan

I saw this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58912/how-do-i-decode-the-transactions-log-with-web3-py/59288#59288), but there are contracts like [the pcs's router](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code) which have no `event` defined in [the contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code), see [this transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x4e07578a43f627e3a9fb2757cde7f796040868882229a35a68006a0b2aa5e21e) for example.

How can I decode the `logs` in such transactions?

Comment: [Here is a ready-made Python library function to decode PancakeSwap transactions](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade.html#eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa your shared link is dead

Comment: [Here is a fixed link](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade_by_receipt.html#eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis.analyse_trade_by_receipt)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Fixed link is also dead :)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the logs related to transaction using [`Eth.get_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=receipt#web3.eth.Eth.get_transaction_receipt) . `web3` should be connected into the network you are using, where the transaction is deployed.

> ````py
> >>> web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt('0x5c504ed432cb51138bcf09aa5e8a410dd4a1e204ef84bfed1be16dfba1b22060')
> AttributeDict({
>     'blockHash': '0x4e3a3754410177e6937ef1f84bba68ea139e8d1a2258c5f85db9f1cd715a1bdd',
>     'blockNumber': 46147,
>     'contractAddress': None,
>     'cumulativeGasUsed': 21000,
>     'from': '0xA1E4380A3B1f749673E270229993eE55F35663b4',
>     'gasUsed': 21000,
>     'logs': [],
>     'logsBloom': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...0000',
>     'status': 1, # 0 or 1
>     'to': '0x5DF9B87991262F6BA471F09758CDE1c0FC1De734',
>     'transactionHash': '0x5c504ed432cb51138bcf09aa5e8a410dd4a1e204ef84bfed1be16dfba1b22060',
>     'transactionIndex': 0, }) ```
> ````

---

From here you can fetch the `logs`, which should return transaction Receipt Event Logs corresponding to [here](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x4e07578a43f627e3a9fb2757cde7f796040868882229a35a68006a0b2aa5e21e#eventlog).

```py
>>> tx = web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt('0x4e07578a43f627e3a9fb2757cde7f796040868882229a35a68006a0b2aa5e21e')
>>> logs = tx["logs"]
```

Comment: I don't have a problem until here. I'm connected to network. I send a transaction and it will be approved by bsc and I'll get back a reciept. I've got "tx" and "logs".  I have no `event name` in `events`.

Comment: check the contract of pancakeswap router above in the question. there is no event defined in the source code. also in the documents on the pcs website, there is no information about `events` in the router's contract but functions

Comment: I got it but the pancakeswap function may call other contract's function, I believe they migh have the events that are trigger

Comment: I do see events in `contracts\interfaces\IPancakePair.sol` in the source code (https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPancakePair.sol)

Comment: thanks man, so I've to figure out why `contract.events` is not populated with events

Comment: @irajjelodari did you finally find a way to parse the logs? I'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

[This is solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144311/114258) how to decode data from log, without any adition network requests.

```py
w3 = Web3(provider=Web3.HTTPProvider("your_RPC_provider"))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=contract_abi)
eld = EventLogDecoder(contract)

result = {
'address': '0x45dda9cb7c25131df268515131f647d726f50608', 
'topics': ['0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67', '0x0000000000000000000000004c60051384bd2d3c01bfc845cf5f4b44bcbe9de5', '0x000000000000000000000000a1bc0292191192b6f03fc0045a26592ce4719bba'], 
'data': '0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff4af79b90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000199430ac4f396b900000000000000000000000000000000000060344446a57b653f75b746ecd6e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001db24a4d833c90130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031603', 
'blockNumber': '0x25235e9', 
'transactionHash': '0x03c147dd2c1e1e65b01628b1adc1e268db7188b7c4de2d38e1964a96f3395073',
'transactionIndex': '0x4e', 
'blockHash': '0x57ebe7b3dd2a3c0bf9cc7191bbaeb49f74043f2da81bb98220874909b040b6a0',
'logIndex': '0x142', 
'removed': False
}

out = eld.decode_log(result)
```

`EventLogDecoder` definition is in [solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144311/114258).