# How to read multiple destination transactions?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, method

I have a system that read normal token transactions with the 0xa9059cbb method, but now I'm receiving transactions like this 0x5ed78dc97ed6c4a3797be99f04977bbcfd45ca5c0ae97ade16dce69e7ecc558a with multiple destinations that I'm not familiar.

What method this transaction use? Is 0xca350aa6 a valid method? Can someone guide me on where can I find more information on how to read those kind of transactions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [0xA9D1e08C7793af67e9d92fe308d5697FB81d3E43](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa9d1e08c7793af67e9d92fe308d5697fb81d3e43) is not verified and also input data on [0x5ed78dc97ed6c4a3797be99f04977bbcfd45ca5c0ae97ade16dce69e7ecc558a](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5ed78dc97ed6c4a3797be99f04977bbcfd45ca5c0ae97ade16dce69e7ecc558a) may contains the tuple so it will be hard to try to analyze its input data.

Who knows, the developer don't want to share it so can make it more difficult to analyze than normal.

But there's one thing that the developer can not change.

It's the transfer event on ERC-20 contract and developer must call transfer function on ERC-20 and this transfer function emit **Transfer** event.

You can check about these transfers on https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5ed78dc97ed6c4a3797be99f04977bbcfd45ca5c0ae97ade16dce69e7ecc558a#eventlog .

You can see how to do it pragmatically on here.
[How do I parse the transaction receipt log with web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are just fetching transactions and filtering by the signature `transfer(address,uint256)`. This will not catch all token transfers as this is only transactions that are directly calling and transferring from an EOA (Externally Owned Account, i.e. a private key and not a contract). You wont get transfers that are coming from contracts, like your example tx is doing

It's also possible you get false positives as the signature is only 4 bytes, so there will be collisions, and you may consider non-transfer transactions as transfers.

The proper way to get ERC20 transfers is by fetching the `Transfer` events emitted on the token contract. This will give you the transfers within a transaction regardless of whether the user called it directly or if it was called by a contract